# Prepend a # to the first line not already having a #

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with options for a command I run. Whenever I run the command I want it to run with the options defined in the first line which is not commented out. I do this using this bash script:

```
while read run opt c; do
  [[ $run == \#* ]] && continue
  ./submit.py $opt $run -c "$c"
  break
done < to_submit.txt
```

The file to_submit.txt has entries like this:

```
#167993 options/optionfile.py long description
167995 options/other_optionfile.py other long description
...
```

After having run the submit script with the options in the last not commented out line, I want to comment out that line after the command ran successfully.

I can find the line number of the options I used adding this to the while loop:

```
line=$(grep -n "$run" to_submit.txt | grep "$opt" | grep "$c" | cut -f 1 -d ":")
```

But I'm not sure how to actually prepend a # to that line now. I could probably use head and tail to save the other lines and process that line separately and combine it all back into the file. But this sounds like it's to complicated, there must be an easier sed or awk solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *GNU* `sed` is probably simplest here:

```
sed '0,/^[^#]/ s//#&/' file
```

<sup>Add option `-i` if you want to update `file` in place.</sup>

- `'0,/^[^#]/` matches all lines up to and including the first one that doesn't start with `#`
- `s//#&/` then prepends `#` to that line.

  - Note that `s//.../` (i.e., an *empty* regex) reuses the last matching regex in the range, which is `/^[^#]/` in this case.

<sup>Note that the command doesn't work with BSD/OSX `sed`, unfortunately, because starting a range with `0` so as to allow the range *endpoint* to match the very first line also is not supported there. It *is* possible to make the command work with BSD/OSX `sed`, but it's more cumbersome.</sup>

Comment: I knew there must be some sed fu to do this. It also looks slightly more readable than the awk oneline from Ed.

Comment: Yes, it is a more direct expression of the intent than the `awk` answer, but the _form_ that the expression takes and the implicitly applied rules are probably still obscure to the uninitiated.

Comment: Ended up using this solution.

Comment: Yes, but then again, almost all sed looks like magic to me :)

Comment: @Graipher - to avoid the magical runes here's all you need to understand about sed: `sed -n 's/regexp/string/gp'`. For anything else, just use awk. There will be the occasional time when a sed solution is a bit briefer and might even look a bit clearer but it's just not worth bothering with those few cases since it might not be portable (as in this case) and certainly won't be extensible as requirements change, etc. Just make sure you understand the sed commands s, g, and p (with -n) and read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn how to do everything else.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk '!f && sub(/^[^#]/,"#&"){f=1} 1' file
#167993 options/optionfile.py long description
#167995 options/other_optionfile.py other long description
...
```

To overwrite the contents of the original file:

```
awk '!f && sub(/^[^#]/,"#&"){f=1} 1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

just like with any other UNIX command.

Comment: Also nice answer, even though I find mklement0's sed answer slightly more readable. I knew my awk knowledge being too small was why I couldn't find a nicer solution in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If the input/output file is not very large, you can do it all in Bash:

```
optsfile=to_submit.txt

has_run_cmd=0
outputlines=()
while IFS= read -r inputline || [[ -n $inputline ]] ; do
    read run opt c <<<"$inputline"
    if (( has_run_cmd )) || [[ $run == \#* ]] ; then
        outputlines+=( "$inputline" )
    elif ./submit.py "$opt" "$run" -c "$c" ; then
        has_run_cmd=1
        outputlines+=( "#$inputline" )
    else
        exit $?
    fi
done < "$optsfile"

(( has_run_cmd )) && printf '%s\n' "${outputlines[@]}" > "$optsfile"
```

The lines of the file are put in the `outputlines` array, with a hash prepended to the line that was used in the `./submit.py` command.  If the command runs successfully, the file is overwritten with the lines in `outputlines`.

Answer (score -1):

After some searching around I found that

```
awk -v run="$run" -v opt="$opt" '{if($1 == run && $2 == opt) {print "#" $0} else print}' to_submit.txt > temp
mv -b -f temp to_submit.txt
```

seems to solve this (without needing to find the line number first, just comparing $ run and $opt). This assumes that the combination of run and opt is enough to identify a line and the comment is not needed (which happens to be true in my case). Not sure how the comment which is spanning multiple fields in awk would also be taken into account.

Comment: There's no guarantee that `cat to_submit.txt` will read the entire contents of its input before `tee to_submit.txt` truncates it. It's best to write your output to a temporary file, then rename that file to your original input once the replacement has succeeded.

Comment: Never write to the file you are reading for the reason @chepner states. Also avoid UUOC (google it).

Comment: Yeah, I just found that out myself by wiping the entire file... Good thing I have backups. Edited with temp file and without use of cat.